# Quotation marks inside <pre> element showing as â€œ or similar character

Tags: html

I'm just trying to post a simple html file consisting mainly of some prose I wrote inside of `<pre>` elements.
Interestingly, when I view the file on my computer with my browser, the quotation marks display fine. But when I upload it to my website, quotation marks are rendered as something like `â€œ` or `â€`. I have looked around the web for solutions but they were few and in between.

I tried to use the meta tag and included

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8" />
```

to my header but to no avail. Any ideas on how to solve this? It just wouldn't make sense to go back to the content inside the  elements and code it into html as the prose is a draft and will go through many changes in the future.

Comment: Can you share the html file ?

Comment: Please share the HTML code that you have used so far. Otherwise, it would be difficult for us to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

The `<!doctype html>` tag indicates the file is HTML5 - so the browser will render it as such. `lang="en"` should be set to the language you are working with. Be sure to use the `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag to set the character set in the `<head>`

```
<!doctype html>    
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Template</title>
</head>
<body>
  <pre>This is my stuff</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Check your code with the browser's View Source and use the Validator at https://validator.w3.org/ to check the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I tried.

```
<!doctype html>    
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <pre>Einstein said,"Once you stop learning, you start dying"</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried only this

```
<body>
  <pre>Einstein said,"Once you stop learning, you start dying"</pre>
</body>
```

Still working